# Why IE11 render a blank page, as I run a Gatsby Project/ react Project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-11, gatsby

`package.json` I have:

```
"browserslist": [
    ">2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all",
    "ie>=11"
  ],
```

I am using Gatsby version:  `"gatsby": "^2.20.27"`

---

In the console I have this error:

[image: Error Image]]

Comment: Gatsby provides IE11 support by default. However, if you internally use a JavaScript function that doesn't have support in that browser (such as `new Url()`, etc) the browser won't be able to display the page. Without more information is really hard to try to figure out where the problem comes from but as far as I know Gatsby and IE11, you have a function that is not allowed in IE11.

Comment: What do you think about react'polyfill does it solve the problem or not, there should be a solution for that, because still the most company uses the explorer,  explorer should not be able to render all the website. in that websites are used also js.

Comment: Yes, of course, polyfill may solve your issue if you are able to find where the issue comes from. Another workaround is to use legacy functions, there always are multiple ways to reach the same solution.

Comment: From the [Gatsby document](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-support/#polyfills), we can see that the Gatsby leverages Babel 7’s ability to automatically add polyfills for your target browsers. Please try to install babel and use the polyfill.